# Design pattern for distributing many small jobs

Tags: multithreading, design-patterns, scheduler

Is there a specialized design pattern for this problem?
I'm developing a molucule modeler application and I need to compute a lot of 1D integrals independently. And again and again with slightly different parameters.
I need a certain scheduler that distributes the integral parameters to the working threads then collects the output in a responsive and monitorable manner.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Cyclic Barrier can be used. In this, the runners execute small tasks and all wait at a thread and the response can be accumulated, once all completes. 

In Java you can check on CompletableFuture.

You can submit your tasks and all the responses can be blocked.  at a point.

Comment: Well, I use C++. I know, I did not add it to the question. Also, I'd like to eliminate idle states, so  the working threads must run independently.